# Using a select Statement (with multiple results) as an input parameter for Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have two tables. Episodes, and Assessments. Each Episode is made up of multiple Assessments.

SQL Server 2005.

I have a fully functioning DeleteAssessment Stored procedure that accepts the AssessmentID as an input parameter and deletes it. I'm trying to setup a DeleteEpisode assessment that, before deleting the Episode, calls the DeleteAssessment Stored procedure to delete all the related assessments. I believe this code further explains what I want to do..

```
EXEC DeleteAssessment (SELECT AssessmentID FROM Assessments WHERE EpisodeID = @EpisodeID)
```

The select statement as the parameter will return multiple assessmentID's which I then need to pass to the DeleteAssessment Stored Procedure.

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This is a strange way of doing things, why wouldn't you use referential integrity and setup CASCADE deletes / updates to take care of this for you?  Sounds like a simple one to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's not going to work. If DeleteAssessment is complicated enough that you can't just delete the Assessments related to an episode, you need to do something like this in DeleteEpisode:

```
DECLARE @AssessmentID INT;

CREATE TABLE #AssessmentIDs (AssessmentID INT);

INSERT #AssessmentIDs (AssessmentID)

SELECT AssessmentID FROM Assessments WHERE EpisodeID = @EpisodeID;

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #AssessmentIDs WHERE AssesmnentID = @AssessmentID) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @AssessmentID = TOP 1 AssessmentID FROM #AssessmentIDs

    EXEC DeleteAssessment @AssessmentID

    DELETE #AssessmentIDs WHERE AssessmentID = @AssessmentID
END;
```

Comment: This looks good. I'm going to try it out and if it works, I'll give you credit for the answer...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 the correct way is to use a TVP to pass in the relevant table as a parameter.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm in SQL Server 2005.